# Proto.io Toggle Switch/checkbox wont toggle

Tags: html, css

Trying to get a toggle switch to work, and it refuses to toggle, even when data is stripped away/is not applied to the input (data-field attribute applys the data to the toggle). Can anyone see something I don't? all the switching is done using the proto.io CSS. Here's the HTML for it:

```
         <h2 id="workflow-header" class="work-header"></h2>
    <div class="onoffswitch" id="workflow">
        <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="email-switch-thing" data-field="subscribeToWorkflowEmail" {{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}>
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="email-switch-thing">
            <div class="onoffswitch-inner" id="activeworkflow-toggle"></div>
            <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
        </label>

    </div>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #666666; border-radius: 30px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #6BB2ED; color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #666666;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 30px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #666666; border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 56px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px white inset;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but it is working for me. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/skeletonjellies/kmpgf/) I have linked a JSFiddle that I was using to troubleshoot it.

HTML:

```
     <h2 id="workflow-header" class="work-header"></h2>
<div class="onoffswitch" id="workflow">
    <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="email-switch-thing" data-field="subscribeToWorkflowEmail" {{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="email-switch-thing">
        <div class="onoffswitch-inner" id="activeworkflow-toggle"></div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #666666; border-radius: 30px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 16px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    padding-left: 15px;
    background-color: #6BB2ED; color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    padding-right: 15px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #666666;
    text-align: right;
    border-radius: 0 30px 30px 0;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 30px; margin: 0px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #666666; border-radius: 30px;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 56px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(center top, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 80%);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px white inset;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

Researching, the only solution that I could find is that it may be a compatibility issue if you're using IE8, as you need to enable support for it
Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14246902/make-on-off-switch-work-in-ie8-using-proto-io). I hesitate to sound anecdotal, but when I had a problem similar to this using CSS buttons, it turned out to be a simple compatibility/support issue, which is what leads me to think this.

Answer (score 0):

Steps I followed to execute it successfully:

1) Made one CSS file (enter all data as shared by NeatoBandito) named it : newbtn.css

2) Made one HTML file (enter all data as shared by NeatoBandito remember to include the link href line so that CSS file can be included) named it : newbtn.html

3) Execute HTML file (in the local wamp server, it will execute successfully)

```
<link href="newbtn.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <h2 id="workflow-header" class="work-header"></h2>
<div class="onoffswitch" id="workflow">
    <input type="checkbox" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="email-switch-thing" data-field="subscribeToWorkflowEmail" {{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}>
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="email-switch-thing">
        <div class="onoffswitch-inner" id="activeworkflow-toggle"></div>
        <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>

</div>
```

Thanks for reading.